# El jquery no me funciona dentro del done del ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando traer el valor de un input con jquery, si el valor lo pongo a imprimir fuera del ajax me funciona, pero dentro de la respuesta del ajax no me funciona

```
function guardar(){
console.log($('#orden_div1').val());
var self = this;
var orden_sku = $('#el_qr').val().split('-');
var orden = orden_sku[0];
var sku = orden_sku[1];
var cantidad = 0;
$.ajax({
    url: cantidad_orden,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        _token: $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
        orden: orden,
        articulo: sku,
    },
})
.done(function(res) {
    console.log("entra");
    console.log($('#orden_div1').val());

})
```

}

Para esta pregunta hago referencia a los console.log, el primero de ellos me trae lo que realmente necesito, el console.log("entra") me certifica que la respuesta del ajax si es correcta, el último console.log, que es igual al primero, en este punto me sale vacío y estoy tratando de imprimir lo mismo.

A que se debe esto, cómo se puede solucionar?

Espero haberme hecho entender.

Comment: Aquí no estás seteando nada: `console.log($('#orden_div1').val());` si por ejemplo te interesa mostrar la respuesta en consola puedes hacer `console.log(res);` o si la respuesta es texto plano y la quieres mostrar en el div, puedes hacer algo así: `$('#orden_div1').val(res);`

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido al sitio!

Revisando tu código te consulto: ¿Si se ejecuta el ajax?
me parece que hay una coma de más en:

´´´

```
articulo: sku, //probá eliminar esa coma
```

´´´

¿probastes pasarlo como parámetro? algo así:

´´´

```
$.ajax({            
              url: "SL_ControlMatricula",
              type: "post",
              datatype:"html",
              data: {'idCat':catG,'opcion':opc }, //parámetros
              success: function(data) 
              {
                    $('#Grados').html(data);  
              }
            });
```

´´´

También te recomiendo checar este enlace: https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/fundamentos-jquery/capitulo-7/metodos-ajax-de-jquery

es bastante informativo.

Saludos!